# best - fit vs best fit

Tags: hyphenation, business-language, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

I'm having a bit of a disagreement about the use of the words "best fit" vs "best - fit" (note the extra spaces suggested).

The sentence is "...and I enjoy analysing human behaviour and drivers to implement the best fit process and systems."

The suggested sentence is "...and I enjoy analysing human behaviour and drivers to implement best - fit process and systems."

The first seems correct to me. It is in the context of a resume so am I missing something?

Comment: There's never spaces around the hyphen in a compound word. It's either "best fit" or "best-fit".

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar. I definitely agree.